# Bash - sort filenames based on multiple fields

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a collection of files such as

```
fa_1_se-1.xml  
fa_1_se-2.xml
fa_1_se-3.xml
fa_1_se-10.xml   
fa_2_se-1.xml  
fa_2_se-2.xml
fa_2_se-12.xml
```

where the number after the underscore indicates the person_id and the number after the hyphen is the record_id.

I am trying to sort them by person_id first and then record_id without success.

`ls | sort -t- -k2` gives

```
f_a_1_se-1.xml
f_a_2_se-1.xml
f_a_1_se-10.xml
f_a_2_se-12.xml
f_a_1_se-2.xml
f_a_2_se-2.xml
f_a_1_se-3.xml
```

How can I get it to sort by person_id and then record_id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--stable` option:

```
sort --stable -t_ -nk2 file
fa_1_se-1.xml
fa_1_se-2.xml
fa_1_se-3.xml
fa_1_se-10.xml
fa_2_se-1.xml
fa_2_se-2.xml
fa_2_se-12.xml
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also try:

```
printf "%s\n" fa* | tr '-' '_' | sort -t_ -nk2 -nk4 | sed 's/_\([^_]*\)$/-\1/'
```

Comment: I tried the stable option with `ls fa* | sort --stable -t_ -nk2` but it doesn't produce the correct output.. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Above is direct copy / paste for sort output  I get. Parsing output from `ls` has many pitfalls.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realise there were issues with ls. What's the best way to get file names into the file? Thanks

Comment: Try this: `ls | sort -t- -k2 -sn | sort -t_ -k2 -sn`

Comment: @dopplesoldner: Try this `printf "%s\n" fa* | tr '-' '_' | sort -t_ -nk2 -nk4 | sed 's/_\([^_]*\)$/-\1/'`

Comment: Thanks! This works great! 
Didn't know about the `tr` command, will definitely keep in mind in the future!

Answer (score 1):

For data that is not presorted in any way- one method is a tag sort, sort by tags:

```
awk -F '[_-\.]' '{print $2, $4, $0}'  filename | sort -k1n -k2n | awk '{print $3}'
```

where filename has a listing.  `ls` does presort, so @anubhava 's answer seems correct for me.  This example is just an add-on.